# Moving files from directory to a sub-directory, except one directory

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-server-2003

I need to move files from the sub-directories to the root directory using the Window's CMD, however when the directory name is "Sent" the script should ignore this sub-directory.

Right now I have this...

```
 for /r "C:/example" %x in (*.txt) do move "%x" "C:\example"
```

Is there any *if* for the CMD?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /r "c:\example" %x in (.) do if /i not "%~nxx"=="Sent" move "%~fx\*.txt" "c:\example"
```

For each directory under c:\example, if name of directory (`%~nxx`) is not Sent (test is case insensitive `/i`) move all the txt files in directory (indicating full path of directory `%~fx`) to c:\example

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however i'm getting the following message: `The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~fx\*.txt" "c:\example"`, I'm going to try to play around with it and see it works. :)